# Как правильно составить регулярку для поиска номера телефона в тексте?

Tags: php

Помогите составить регулярное выражение для поиска номера телефона в  тексте в международном формате , чтобы оставался лишь номер телефона. типа вот так +79119068771

Например, есть текст:

```
Карта Сбербанк - 5469550021126526
Оплата Яндекс деньги :+7(903)888-88-88
Номер кошелька: 41001194625877
Киви Кошелек - +79119068771
Кошелек - +380119068771
Тел +972 54 77 22 765
Москва. 31.03.2018г.
Зароботок 3000$
+7-906-107-97-10
```

Как составить регулярное выражение, чтобы исключить из текста дату (31.03.2018г.), а также вот такие цифры (3000$), и удалять пробелы и тире из номера?

Делаю вот так:

```
preg_match('~(\+[\d- ()]+)~', $descr_full, $number); //парсим номер тел

preg_match('/(\+\d+)?\s*(\(\d+\))?([\s-]?\d+)+/', $descr_full, $number);

preg_match('/((\+\d+[\s\-\.]?)?((\(\d+\)|\d+)[\s\-\.]?)?(\d[\s\-\.]?){5,6}\d)/x', $descr_full, $number);

echo $phone = $number[1];
```

Comment: формат номера телефона может быть разным или фиксированным?  скобки, дефисы, пробелы, плюсы и т.д.

Comment: я не знаю как лучше разное или фиксированное  ну вот чтоб осталось например так +79119068771

Comment: ты не понял. ТЕБЕ данные в каком формате будут приходить?

Comment: это разные данные неизвестные я привел пример какой может быть текст

Comment: Я бы наверное взял все цифры с знаками припинания в середине. Потом вырезал все лишние знаки, оставив только цифры и отбросил те, что короче скажем 6 цифр. Но конечно кроме телефонов там будет еще куча других длинных чисел. И с этим боюсь ничего не сделать, даже если у вас будет справочник всех кодов стран/городов и длины номеров внутри населенных пунктов (хотя такой справочник изрядно бы почистил информацию)

Comment: типа вот так  `$number = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", $number); // стерли лишнее, оставили цифры

$number = preg_replace("#(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})#", "+\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5", $number); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ориентироваться по символу "`+`", то можно получить все телефонные номера таким способом:

```
$str = 'Карта Сбербанк - 5469550021126526
Оплата Яндекс деньги :+7(903)888-88-88
Номер кошелька: 41001194625877
Киви Кошелек - +79119068771
Кошелек - +380119068771
Тел +972 54 77 22 765
Москва. 31.03.2018г.
Зароботок 3000$
+7-906-107-97-10';

$numbs = [];

if (preg_match_all('~\+\d[(\d\h-)]+\b~', $str, $arr)) {
    $arr = $arr[0];
    $numbs = str_replace(['(', ')', '-', ' '], '', $arr);
}


var_export($numbs);
```

В результате будет массив номеров:

```
array (
  0 => '+79038888888',
  1 => '+79119068771',
  2 => '+380119068771',
  3 => '+972547722765',
  4 => '+79061079710',
)
```

Comment: у меня на денвере выходит ошибка  для квадратных скобок [ ]

Comment: @PetroBoyko это из-за вашей устаревшей версии php. Давно пора бы сменить Денвер на _(как минмум)_ OpenServer. Для корректной работы скрипта на вашей версии PHP нужно заменить все сокращённые объявления массивов, т.е. вместо этих двух записей `$numbs = [];` и `$numbs = str_replace(['(', ')', '-', ' '], '', $arr);` нужно записать так: `$numbs = array();` и `$numbs = str_replace(array('(', ')', '-', ' '), '', $arr);` соответственно.